# 'Only those that are clean in thine house shall eat of it.' What does that mean?

Tags: numbers

> And this is thine; the heave offering of their gift, with all the wave offerings of the children of Israel: I have given them unto thee, and to thy sons and to thy daughters with thee, by a statute for ever: every one that is clean in thy house shall eat of it. [Numbers 18:11, KJV.]

In Numbers 18:11, of the offerings mentioned in Numbers 18:9 it states that only those that are clean in thine house shall eat of it. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

'Only those that are clean in thine house shall eat of it.' What does that mean?

Numbers 18:11  (NET Bible)

> 11 “And this is yours: the raised offering of their gift, along with
>   all the wave offerings of the Israelites. I have given them to you and
>   to your sons and daughters with you as a perpetual ordinance. Everyone
>   who is ceremonially clean in your household may eat of it."

Responsibilities of the Priests- Levites. The priests were required to keep  high standards of personal cleanliness and moral standards, only those that were ceremoniously clean could  eat of the offerings. Regulations for the Eating of Priestly Stipends. Read,  Leviticus 22:1-9. 4-6 noted below.

Leviticus 22:4-6  (NET Bible)

> 4 "No man from the descendants of Aaron who is diseased or has a
>   discharge may eat the holy offerings until he becomes clean. The one
>   who touches anything made unclean by contact with a dead person, or a
>   man who has a seminal emission, 5 or a man who touches a swarming
>   thing by which he becomes unclean, or touches a person by which he
>   becomes unclean, whatever that person’s impurity— 6 the person who
>   touches any of these will be unclean until evening and must not eat
>   from the holy offerings unless he has bathed his body in water."